# How to check if a Rectangle resides within a Bitmap

Tags: c#, .net

I am trying to create a function which says whether a `Rectangle(int x, int y, int width, int height)` resides within a Bitmap image. Here `x` or `y` can be `>= 0`

```
public bool RectangleIsinBitmap(Rectangle rec)
{
    Bitmap bitmap = new Bitmap(500, 500);
    if(//rec resides in bitmapImg )
        return true;
    else
        return false;
}
```

Any ideas or thoughts are much appreciated.

Comment: I suggest you draw your bitmap and a couple of rectangles on a piece of paper with their respective positions and dimensions and see if you can't come up with the statements needed to identify whether a given rectangle is within the bounds of the bitmap.

Comment: What have you tried so far? What research have you done? This should be a fairly simple to do with just basic math knowledge.

Comment: This is a really really trivial task (especially when Rectangle has properties for Left, Top, Right, and Bottom). What is the specific issue you're facing here?

Comment: You are creating an unneeded Bitmap and then leaking it. All you need it to compare the size and location. Use Rectangle.contains(Rectangle) !

Comment: @TaW Thank you. This is what I was looking for. Did not have to do the regular math.